# Upload Plugin issues

Tags: cakephp, plugins, file-upload, cakephp-2.2

Trying to get the [CakePHP Upload Plug-in](https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload) to work.  The file uploads fine, the thumbnails are created...etc, but having a few issues:

-the 'name' field in the 'uploads' table is empty

-the 'upload' field in the 'uploads' table is empty ('attachment' field in the doc example)

-if I use {model} in the 'path' set in the Upload model, it uses 'upload' as the model folder - it should go in a folder of the associated model, not the upload model every time

```
//Upload MODEL
public $actsAs = array(
    'Upload.Upload' => array(
        'photo' => array(
            'thumbnailSizes' => array(
                'xvga' => '1024x768',
                'vga' => '640x480',
                'thumb' => '80x80',
            ),
            'thumbnailMethod' => 'php',
            'path' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}uploads{DS}{model}{DS}{field}{DS}', 
            'maxSize' => '5242880', //5MB
            'mimetypes' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'image/bmp'),
            'extensions' => array('jpg', 'gif', 'png'),
        ),
    )
);

//ArticleData MODEL
public $hasMany = array(
    'Upload' => array(
        'className' => 'Upload',
        'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Upload.model' => 'ArticleData',
        ),
    ),
);

//CONTROLLER
public function admin_upload() {        
    if(!empty($this->request->data)) {
        $this->loadModel('Upload');
        debug($this->request->data);
        if($this->Upload->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('SAVED!!!!!!!!');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('NOT SAVED!!!!!!!!');
        }
    }
}

// VIEW
echo $this->Form->create('ArticleData', array('type'=>'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('Upload.model', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>'ArticleData'));
echo $this->Form->input('Upload.foreign_key', array('type'=>'hidden', 'value'=>'4f93676e-347c-4e0c-8e6c-0a3cadcd7f7c'));
echo $this->Form->input('Upload.photo', array('type'=>'file'));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

Answer (score 0):

Dave:

> -the 'name' field in the 'uploads' table is empty

This is normal, I think is is more of a "display" name field as opposed to "filename" field. The name should be stored in the "photo" field in your example.

> -if I use {model} in the 'path' set in the Upload model, it uses 'upload' as the model folder - it should go in a folder of the associated model, not the upload model every time

You'll want to alias the model, like so:

```
//ArticleData MODEL
public $hasMany = array(
    'AliasModelHere' => array(
        'className' => 'Upload',
        'foreignKey' => 'foreign_key',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Upload.model' => 'ArticleData',
        ),
    ),
);

// Then

$this->ArticleData->AliasModelHere->save($data)
```